# Why is the supercurrent the functional derivative of the Ginzberg Landau free energy with respect to the vector potential?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

In the book "Superconductivity, Superfluids and Condensates", they write down the macroscopic free energy to be

> $$ F_s(T) = F_n(T) + \int\left(\frac{1}{2m^*}\left|\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla + 2e \boldsymbol{A}\right)\psi\right|^2 + a|\psi|^2+\frac{b}{2}|\psi|^4 \right) d^3r + \frac{1}{2\mu_0} \int B(\boldsymbol{r})^2d^3r $$

where $F_n$ is the free energy of the normal state. Then they claim that the supercurrent can be written by

> $$ \boldsymbol{j}_s = \frac{\partial F_s}{\partial \boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{r})}$$

My question is, how did you get this equation rigorously? It 'seems' to me somehow that one can vaguely say that the current is always couple to the vector potential in the Hamiltonian. But it looks very hand wavy to me if one wants to explain it like that. Is there any better way to derive this expression?

Comment: Quick hint: Vector potential acts like a source field in partition function and free energy is proportional to logarithm of partition function.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the same book and have the same confusion.
Here is another pdf on GL.
[http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/~mcc/Ph127/c/Lecture14.pdf](http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/%7Emcc/Ph127/c/Lecture14.pdf)
Where eqn 3-5 reproduce the same result, but using (functional) dF/dA = 0 and the derived equation together with curl.B = j give the supercurrent. This makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

The transparent way is to just take the variational derivative of free energy with respect to $A$ and put it equal to zero (NOT equal to current) and see that one will get the Ampere's law for $B$ with a current given by the minus of the functional derivative of the **first term** in the free energy with respect to $A$.